# Horizontal scrolling with sticky div that stays on the left border

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have two rows of data (green) and a header (red), which should be visible at all times:

Check out the example I already have:

http://jsfiddle.net/j9C8R/33/

Now the red header scrolls away together with the content, but it should stick to where it is now, but scroll vertically with the content (MS Excel style).

How can this be achieved (preferably with only CSS).

**UPDATE**: It is important that the red headers scroll vertically along with the corresponding content but stick to the left edge when scrolling horizontally.

```css
.main {
  background-color: blue;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
}

.row {
  height: 50px;
  overflow: scroll;
  clear: both;
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.sticky,
.content {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.sticky {
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sticky">Sticky header A</div>
    <div class="content">ContentA</div>
    <div class="content">ContentA</div>
    <div class="content">ContentA</div>
    <div class="content">ContentA</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sticky">Sticky header B</div>
    <div class="content">ContentB</div>
    <div class="content">ContentB</div>
    <div class="content">ContentB</div>
    <div class="content">ContentB</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sticky">Sticky header C</div>
    <div class="content">ContentC</div>
    <div class="content">ContentC</div>
    <div class="content">ContentC</div>
    <div class="content">ContentC</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sticky">Sticky header D</div>
    <div class="content">ContentD</div>
    <div class="content">ContentD</div>
    <div class="content">ContentD</div>
    <div class="content">ContentD</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="sticky">Sticky header E</div>
    <div class="content">ContentE</div>
    <div class="content">ContentE</div>
    <div class="content">ContentE</div>
    <div class="content">ContentE</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE**

please note the below is now a little out of date as we have css [position sticky](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

**Original Post**

I do not think it is possible to achieve your goal through pure css as items that are sticky usually use `position:fixed` which unfortunately fixes them relative to the viewport.

with the use of javascript (in this case the jquery library) and absolute positioning, you should be able to achieve what you are after:

```js
$('.main').scroll(function() {
    $(this).find('.sticky').css('left', $(this).scrollLeft());
});
```

```css
.main {
    background-color:blue;
    overflow:scroll;
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
}
.row {
    height:50px;
    overflow:scroll;
    clear:both;
    width:1000px;
    position:relative;
    background-color:yellow;
    padding-left:150px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}
.sticky, .content {
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
.sticky {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute; left:0; top:0;
}
.content {
    background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sticky">I should stick to the left border</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sticky">I should stick to the left border</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sticky">I should stick to the left border</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sticky">I should stick to the left border</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="sticky">I should stick to the left border</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
        <div class="content">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, I did not think that it would be that easy. I can handle one line of javascript like that.

Comment: the only problem with this is that it is not 100% smooth

Comment: @MartinZvarík that's why you should use position sticky

Comment: @Pete Oh yeah, didn't notice that you've updated the post already... yes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've scrapped your thing and have made a complete new one, I've just not wrapped up things inside a position relative container but you can manage to do it atleast

The things are easy for vertical scroll but if you expect horizontal scroll and move headers along, (CSS Wont Just Do It)

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/j9C8R/16/)

CSS

```
.head {
    background-color: #f00;
    width: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 100px;
}

.head table {
    width: 100%;
}

.body {
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.body table {
    width: 100%;
}

.body td {
    width: 100px;
}

.head table td {
    width: 100px;
}

.left {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #0f0;
    width: 90px;
    top: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not what I try to achieve. The red divs should scroll together with the corresponding content. I've updated my answer, as well as the jsfiddle accordingly.

Comment: @Besi Yea, so you cannot do with CSS only :) you should add jQuery, JS tags to your question

Comment: I did this. However, it is hard to imagine that this is not possible with CSS. One example that comes to my mind right now are those HTML-based text editors, which have line numbers but scrolling code (horizontally) which don't push away the line numbers. I wonder how they do it.

Comment: @Besi If you are talking about online code editors than they use JS, if you are talking about `.exe` local software than it is entirely different thing