# How to fix left div when scrolling horizontally and fix top when scrolling vertically (Excel like)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to do kind of like excel.  Have my top header fixed when scrolling vertically and my left "header" fixed when scrolling horizontally.

Here is my HTML with embedded style and CSS after that

http://jsfiddle.net/qDFn8/1/

html:

```
<div id="resourceChart">
    <div class="leftPart ui-resizable">
        <div class="header"></div>
        <div class="leftContainer">
            <div class="item parent">
                <div style="float:left;" class="leftcollapse toggleMinus"></div>John Smith</div>
            <div class="item child" style="display: block;">My Work</div>
            <div class="item child" style="display: block;">My Second Work</div>
            <div class="item parent">
                <div style="float:left;" class="leftcollapse toggleMinus"></div>Bob Doe</div>
            <div class="item child" style="display: block;">My Work</div>
            <div class="item child" style="display: block;">Activity2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="gantMainControl" id="gantControl">
        <div class="gant-compareitem" style="margin-top:41px;width:138px;margin-left:368px;"></div>
        <div id="gantHeader" class="header">
            <div class="headerRow">
                <div class="headerRowYear" id="headerYear">
                    <div class="headerCellYear" style="width:547px">2013</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="headerRow">
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">J</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:42px">F</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">M</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:45px">A</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">M</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:45px">J</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">J</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">A</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:45px">S</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">O</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:45px">N</div>
                <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:47px">D</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container summary" style="margin-top:0px;">
            <div class="timelineContainer" style="width: 551px;">
                <div class="summaryColumn" style="width:297px;">
                    <div>94%</div>
                    <div style="width:100%;height:3px;background-color:yellow;"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="summaryColumn last" style="width: 247px;">
                    <div>2%</div>
                    <div style="width:100%;height:3px;background-color:yellow"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="display: block;">
            <div class="timelineContainer child" style="width: 551px;">
                <div class="timeline normal-timeline" style="margin-left:1px;width:298.4375px;">92%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="display: block;">
            <div class="timelineContainer child" style="width: 551px;">
                <div class="timeline normal-timeline" style="margin-left:1px;width:547.5px;">2%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container summary">
            <div class="timelineContainer" style="width: 551px;">
                <div class="summaryColumn last" style="width: 547px;">
                    <div>75%</div>
                    <div style="width:100%;height:3px;background-color:yellow"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="display: block;">
            <div class="timelineContainer child" style="width: 551px;">
                <div class="timeline normal-timeline" style="margin-left:1px;width:547.5px;">72%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container" style="display: block;">
            <div class="timelineContainer child" style="width: 551px;">
                <div class="timeline normal-timeline" style="margin-left:1px;width:547.5px;">3%</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html{
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.leftPart {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
}

.leftPart .header {
    background-color:white;
    border:1px lightblue solid;
    display:inline-block;
    width:194px;
    height: 39px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}

.toggleExpand {
    background-image: url(../../../Images/Icons/plus.png);
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.toggleMinus {
    background-image: url(../../../Images/Icons/minus.png);
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
.leftPart .item {
    background-color:white;
    border:1px lightblue solid;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:194px;
    margin-top:-1px;
    height: 23px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.leftPartselector {
    width: 30px;
    float: left;
}

.leftPartselector .header {
    background-color:white;
    border:1px lightblue solid;
    display:inline-block;
    width:24px;
    height: 39px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;

}


.leftPartselector .item{
    background-color:white;
    border:1px lightblue solid;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
    width:24px;
    margin-top:-1px;
    height: 23px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}


.leftPart .child {
    text-indent: 20px;
}

.gantMainControl {
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.leftContainer {
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

.gantMainControl .header {
    width:90%;
    height: 40px;
}

.gantMainControl .headerRow {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 21px;
}

.gantMainControl .headerRow .headerCellMonth {
    margin-right:-2px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    background-color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid lightblue;
    white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-align:center;
}
.gantMainControl .headerRow .headerCellYear {
    background-color:white;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid lightblue;
    text-align:center;
    margin-right:-1px;
}

.gantMainControl .headerRow .headerRowYear {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
}

.gantMainControl .container {
    border: hidden 1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    height: 25px;
}

.gantMainControl .container .timelineContainer {
   display:inline-block;
    height: 24px;
}

.gantMainControl .container .timelineContainer:hover{
   background-color:#d0e9fa;
}


.gantMainControl .container .timeline {
    height: 18px;
    background-color: #97C9EB;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 18px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

.gantMainControl .container .normal-timeline {
    border: 1px white solid;
}

.summaryColumn {
    height: 22px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: grey;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
}

.summaryColumn div {
      white-space:nowrap;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow:ellipsis;
}

div.ui-tooltip {
    max-width: 500px;
}
.tooltip {
    font-size: 10px;
}
.tooltip td {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}

.tooltip span{
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-right: 5px;  
}

.gantt-pager {
    padding-right: 4px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}


.gant-compareitem {
    background-color: rgba(148, 202, 252, 0.3); /* browsers */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#97C9EBff', endColorstr='#97C9EBff'); /* IE */
    height: 99%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    border-left: 2px solid purple;
    border-right: 2px solid purple;
}
```

Comment: It seems to be working for the most part... so all you need to do is fix the top header then?

Comment: Exactly, the problem is fixing the top header while having the left one fixed... Only one is easy but doing it for the two of them ...

Comment: Try this example. I believe it is something similar you are looking for: [1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086812/horizontal-scrolling-with-sticky-div-that-stays-on-the-left-border?rq=1

Comment: Yeah it is. It's not exactly what I want but I think I can manage with that. I will try it and when I will finished I will post the answer. thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the comment from mario, I've been able to do it using 2 lines of javascript and css.

Here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/QBLdM/4/

and here is the code:

Javascript:

```
$('#resourceChart').scroll(function () {
    $(this).find('.sticky').css('left', $(this).scrollLeft());
});

$('#resourceChart').scroll(function () {
    $(this).find('.stickyv').css('top', $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="resourceChart">
    <div id="mainSuperContainer">
        <div class="leftPart ui-resizable sticky">
            <div class="header"></div>
            <div class="item parent">
                <div style="float:left;" class="leftcollapse toggleMinus"></div>John Smith</div>
            <div class="item child" style="display: block;">My Work</div>
            <div class="item child" style="display: block;">My Second Work</div>
            <div class="item parent">
                <div style="float:left;" class="leftcollapse toggleMinus"></div>Bob Doe</div>
            <div class="item child" style="display: block;">My Work</div>
            <div class="item child" style="display: block;">Activity2</div>
            <div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gantMainControl " id="gantControl">
            <div id="gantHeader" class="header stickyv">
                <div class="headerRow">
                    <div class="headerRowYear" id="headerYear">
                        <div class="headerCellYear" style="width:547px">2013</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="headerRow">
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">J</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:42px">F</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">M</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:45px">A</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">M</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:45px">J</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">J</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">A</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:45px">S</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:46px">O</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:45px">N</div>
                    <div class="headerCellMonth" style="width:47px">D</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='mainTimelineContainer'>
                <div class="container summary" style="margin-top:0px;">
                    <div class="timelineContainer" style="width: 551px;">
                        <div class="summaryColumn" style="width:297px;">
                            <div>94%</div>
                            <div style="width:100%;height:3px;background-color:yellow;"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="summaryColumn last" style="width: 247px;">
                            <div>2%</div>
                            <div style="width:100%;height:3px;background-color:yellow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="timelineContainer child" style="width: 551px;">
                        <div class="timeline normal-timeline" style="margin-left:1px;width:298.4375px;">92%</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="timelineContainer child" style="width: 551px;">
                        <div class="timeline normal-timeline" style="margin-left:1px;width:547.5px;">2%</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container summary">
                    <div class="timelineContainer" style="width: 551px;">
                        <div class="summaryColumn last" style="width: 547px;">
                            <div>75%</div>
                            <div style="width:100%;height:3px;background-color:yellow"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="timelineContainer child" style="width: 551px;">
                        <div class="timeline normal-timeline" style="margin-left:1px;width:547.5px;">72%</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="container" style="display: block;">
                    <div class="timelineContainer child" style="width: 551px;">
                        <div class="timeline normal-timeline" style="margin-left:1px;width:547.5px;">3%</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
#mainTimelineContainer {
    padding-top:42px;
}
#mainSuperContainer {
    width:900px;
    position:relative;
}
.sticky {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:5;
}
.stickyv {
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:5;
}
#resourceChart {
    width:600px;
    height:150px;
    overflow:auto;
}
.gantMainControl {
    padding-left:200px;
}
.gantMainControl .header {
    width:90%;
    height: 40px;
    z-index:1;
    padding-left:200px;
}

.leftPart {
    width:200px;
    float:left;
    z-index:2;
}
.leftPart .header {
    background-color:white;
    border:1px lightblue solid;
    display:inline-block;
    width:194px;
    height: 39px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

CSS:

```
.HeaderRow {
position:fixed;//For vertical purposes
}
```

Javascript(JQUERY):

```
var posWas = $(window).scrollLeft();
$(window).bind('scroll', function(){
var posIs = $(window).scrollLeft();
if(posWas !== posIs){
//Scrolled Horizontal
$('.headerRow').css("position" , "relative");
$('.headerRow').css("left" , posIs );
$('.headerRow').css("position" , "fixed" );
posWas = posIs;//Save it for the Next Run
}
//Scrolled vertically keep as you are
});
```

If you want to fix another class or div please change it in the code.

Comment: Thank you it didnt work with the code you gave me in the fiddle. I will continue to implement the solution Mario showed me.

Comment: @skantanick I am sorry for that but i have tried it on my localhost and it worked for me it could help some body the most important then solution is that you understand the logic that i have written the code with it.

Comment: Thx, I did kind of the same logic with my final solution, using the setting the left position with the scrollLeft, and setting the top position with the scrollTop.

Answer (score 0):

Position fixed and some more CSS, #summary div added in HTML, here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/Ajnrb/), if this is what you wanted...

```
.leftPart {
  position: fixed;
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  z-index: 100;
}

.gantMainControl .header {
  position: fixed;
  left: 211px;
  width:90%;
  height: 40px;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but no, I didn't want everything fixed. I want like Mario put in in comment but both side. I'm implementing that solution