# Scroll the fixed div if scrolling occurs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a layout the was showed in the following demo

http://jsfiddle.net/EX6qV/2/

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='one'> One </div>
  <div class='two'>Two</div>
</div>
```

Here the div `one` has `position:fixed`. I want to scroll the fixed div (One) if scrolling happens.

Due to the fixed position the div sticks at that position hence it overlaps with div two if scroll happens on zooming a page.

Is the any jquery methods to overcome this problem.

Comment: Refer to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086812/horizontal-scrolling-with-sticky-div-that-stays-on-the-left-border/16087477#16087477 - I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Do you mean that your div1 is fixed and if div2 has any image bigger so div1 overlap on div2 and you actually want to aside div1 when div2 has bigger image to prevent overlap?

Comment: plz update jsfiddle with complete example

Comment: Div1 and div2 should not overlap while scrolling. I want something like changing the position and margins of div1 so that avoids overlapping.

Comment: why is div one fixed? for what you ask I would put those two divs with float:left to have them side by side and the scroll will just work. is there a reason for div one to be fixed?