# Nested "position: sticky" element not sticking in Safari, but works in iframe

Tags: css, safari, position, css-position, sticky

I'm using CSS `position: sticky` to stick some elements to my page. I'm using `<div>`s to produce a grid-like structure (`<table>`s aren't appropriate to my use case). Please note that this is specifically a `position: sticky` question - I'm not looking for a Javascript solution, and I believe that `position: sticky` *should* work as desired based on the spec and the behaviour in other browsers.

I need to stick a row for vertical scrolling, and the first cell in that row for horizontal scrolling. If I use `position: sticky; left: 0;` on the first cell *without* sticking the row, the cell sticks to the left just fine. However, **in Safari** if I use eg.

```
.row {
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
    width: ...
}
.cell {
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    width: ...
}
```

the *row* sticks when vertically scrolling as desired but the *cell* does not stick when horizontally scrolling.

The code behaves as desired in Chrome and Firefox, **and** *in an `iframe` in Safari*.

Here's some code for a minimal example:

CSS:

```
.row {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    top: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 2000px;
    z-index: 30;
}
.cell {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
.sticky {
    position: -webkit-sticky;
    position: sticky;
    left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell sticky">Sticky</div>
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
    <div class="cell">Content</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Uploaded files here (can't use codepen/jsfiddle as they load into an iframe):

https://qcn.github.io/minimal_sticky.html Minimal example: doesn't work in Safari, works in Chrome/Firefox

https://qcn.github.io/minimal_sticky_iframe.html The same minimal example loaded into an iframe: does work in Safari!

Another interesting thing I noticed was that if I scroll the page horizontally and then refresh, the sticky cell renders at the left of the viewport, and then scrolls normally in that position (ie. it still doesn't stick, but it knows where it should have been on page load!). This and the fact that the behaviour works inside an iframe and in other browsers makes me suspect it's a browser bug, but I'm unable to find other references to it.

Comment: This has been answered here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/16087477/2843112

Comment: @MatthewT that question does not address my issue - it's a similar use-case but is from before `position: sticky` times and doesn't address the conflicting behaviour seen between browsers here.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a unit. It worked when I wanted to sticky a nested header to the top. I haven't tried your horizontal situation. Hope it helped.

`left: 0px;` instead of `left: 0;`

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be an instance of this bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=106062

I worked around my issue by wrapping the page in a scrolling div to contain it, rather than using viewport scroll. Not ideal but it appears to be a browser bug.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution to this!!!

using `display: contents;`

https://css-tricks.com/get-ready-for-display-contents/