# Boostrap grid sticky left column disappearing after a bit of scrolling

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to make the left-most column of a Bootstrap 4 grid (row / col) be sticky (stays in the same position when scrolling the grid horizontally), but it appears to only stay sticky for a little bit of scrolling, and then it suddenly starts moving out of view.

Here's an example of this issue: https://codepen.io/rquayum/pen/wvMZJgg

```html
...
<div class="row flex-nowrap">
       <div class="col sticky-col">
         Sticky
        </div>
        ...
```

```css
.sticky-col {
  ...
  position: sticky;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

As far as I can tell, it seems like the `row` containing the `col` elements is actually moving out of the scrollable container towards the left. Position sticky does not work if the parent element is no longer in view.

I am not sure why the `row` is behaving this way (I suspect it has something to do with flex). Is there another way of achieving what I want? I cannot use `position: fixed`, as I also wish to have a vertical scroll with fixed column headers as well. I'd also prefer to do this without using Javascript to adjust positions on scroll.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Horizontal scrolling with sticky div that stays on the left border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086812/horizontal-scrolling-with-sticky-div-that-stays-on-the-left-border)

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for a pure CSS solution, but I guess this is the best I can hope for now!

Comment: add these 2 changes: (1) `margin-left: 70px;` inside `.my-cont` (2) `position: fixed;` inside `.sticky-col`

Comment: I cannot use `position: fixed`, as that will prevent the "Sticky" cells from scrolling vertically.